# Support for Service Accounts OAuth2 scenario

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-admin-sdk

Does Directory API support authentication with *OAUth2 Service Accounts* flow?

I tested the [serviceAccount.php google-php-api-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts) example using the scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user` and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you tell us what are the exact errors you get?  Access not configured? or Access denied?

Comment: I'm doing something like this: https://gist.github.com/luissquall/5732977. Client id, service account name, key file and services work fine with Prediction API. I get error "Not Authorized to access this resource/api". The account I used to create the API project have admin permissions over the Google Apps domain and the Admin SDK service is on.

Comment: Hey Luissquall, would you try adding the parameter ?key=[your API access key in API console] in your HTTP request and see if it works?

Comment: Additionally, have you tried downloading the PHP client library for Admin sdk (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/admin/directory_v1/php) <- the link in the documentation isn't working at the moment, but you can use this temporary link to download it for now.

Comment: The link is broken. I got an 404 error.

Comment: Adding key param didn't work. Requests to Drive API using the same service account client ID worked fine but not for Admin SDK.

Comment: Does the account you use have super admin access? I don't think delegated admin works...

Comment: Yes. 3-legged OAuth works using that account.

Comment: I think something is missing here.
setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'
    ),
    $key)
in order for my service account to work, I have an extra parameter of which actual user account I am impersonating. Can you add 
sub 'the admin account email address' in the setAssertionCredentials function
(https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/auth/Google_AssertionCredentials.php)

Comment: I have mine in python and should look like this...

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',  sub='admin@mydomain.com')

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much for your help. I was following the  Prediction API example, Drive API example includes that setting. Have a nice day.

Comment: :) yay! glad to hear that!

Comment: Awesome! Emily's directions helped me a lot.  
In the **JAVA** case:  
`GoogleCredential.setServiceAccountUser()` -- for impersonating;  
Also, check out that you have granted the right scopes to your service account as described here: [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize the service account client ID to access the given API scopes in the Google Apps Control Panel. See the step [as described in the Drive API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account), just sub in your Admin SDK scopes.

Note that IMHO, there's very little advantage to using a Service Account with Directory/Reporting APIs as you still need to impersonate a user who has super admin (or proper delegated admin) roles in order to perform and API calls. To me it makes just as much sense to just get a 3-legged OAuth 2.0 refresh token which supports offline from the admin. 3-legged can be done entirely programmatically where-as Service Accounts require the manual step above.

Comment: Works perfectly for Drive API but not for Admin SDK API. Have you made requests to any of these endpoints (group/user) with a service account client ID? 
Here's the test https://gist.github.com/luissquall/5752799 and the scopes http://f.cl.ly/items/3m3f341A0x2F050D1O0u/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-10%20at%204.47.07%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes**. @emilylam question comments hint the error.